# Running old site on apache + php and new nginx rails side by side

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, seo, nginx

My current site is running on a dedicated server on apache + php.  I am creating my new site in rails and running on nginx.

I want to run both sites together for a while while i slowly redirect all pages SEO rank etc to new site.

My current site has say domain www.mydomain.com and new site will have www.mydomain.com/en infront of everything as will be mulilingual.

My current site is on server A and new site on server B, different locations and i want to figure out the best way to run together.

Can i tell apache on server A to whenever see url www.mydomain.com/en point to server B and nginx on server B with run new rails site?  I am not trying to share sessions so that simplifies things i hope!!!

I can then just turn off server A when ready and just have new site running.

If i cant do this i will have to move all my existing site over to server B and run both sites on same server but think that might take ages and dont want to mess with current site much as to lose traffic / seo ranking etc

Any help, experience or opinions would be gratefully received!

thanks alot
rick

Answer (score 0):

You could run nginx on a different port (e.g. 8080) and then use Apache's mod_proxy to send requests to nginx.

Comment: Same server, just on a different port.